# Return JSON array to jQuery function

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, datepicker

Guys need a help on this, I'm using glDatePicker plugin which takes a JSON array for special dates. Currently I'm fetching Google calender feed for it. but my code is not working as expected. Correct me if I missed something in my code.

glDatePicker takes the special dates as follows and which I'm trying to build dynamically from Google feed:

```
specialDates: [
{
    date: new Date(2014,0,8),
    data: { message: 'Sample event'},
    repeatMonth: false
},
{
    date: new Date(2014,0,1),
    data: { message: 'Happy new Year 2014'},
    repeatMonth: false
}]
```

Here's my HTML

```
<input type="text" id="simple" style="width: 200px; height: 80px; top: 10px; left: 500px; float: right;" />
```

And here's my jQuery

```
jQuery.getJSON("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/srinarayanisociety%40gmail.com/public/full?alt=json", function (data, myObject) {
            var rstr = '[';
            jQuery.each(data.feed.entry, function (key, val) {
                rstr += '{';
                var d = new Date(val.gd$when[0]['startTime']);
                rstr += 'date: new Date(' + d.getFullYear() + ',' + d.getMonth() + ',' + d.getDate() + '),';
                rstr += 'data: { message: \'' + val.title.$t + '\'},';
                rstr += 'repeatMonth: false';
                rstr += '},';
            });
            rstr += rstr.slice(0, -1);
            rstr += rstr + ']';
            alert(rstr);
            jQuery('#simple').glDatePicker({
                showAlways: true,
                selectedDate: new Date(),
                specialDates: rstr,
                onClick: function (target, cell, date, data) {
                    target.val(date.getFullYear() + ' - ' + date.getMonth() + ' - ' + date.getDate());
                    if (data != null) {
                        alert(data.message + '\n' + date);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: Are you getting expected value in `rstr` variable? It will be a string. You may have to convert it into JSON object. Parse the string to json object. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: @AhamedMustafaM Yeah I'm getting proper values, please see the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/cfRG2/93/)

Comment: The `Date` functions in the `rstr` will not be evaluated to form Date objects when you parse the JSON. better form the objects instead of string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can form array of JSON objects as the plugin expects.

```
var dates = [];
                    $.each(data.feed.entry, function (key, val) {
                        var dateObj= {};    
                        dateObj.date=new Date(val.gd$when[0]['startTime']);
                        dateObj.data = {};
                        dateObj.data.message=val.title.$t;
                        dateObj.data.repeatMonth=false;
                        dates.push(dateObj);
                    });
```

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8upG5/).